# missing activity in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Activity for a certain account has gone missing only for a particular year. What all can I do to check what happened. 
The data is not residing in the recycle bin.,there has been no mass delete, checked setupaudittrail as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that those activities have been archived?  See [this doc](https://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/activities_archived.htm) on the automatic activity archiving that goes on.

Comment: I have checked for deleted records as well as archived records. It is showing me activity for the prior year but not specifically for obe year